# Custom Adapter throws exception in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a list view in my Xamarin.Android application. I am creating a custom adapter for my list view, and when I try to use that custom adapter it gives my Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException.

[image: Excetption]

This is the code for my Custom adapter

[image: Custom Adapter]

I am trying to access custom adapter in my MainActivity.cs, and its code for accessing adapter is as follows:

[image: MainActivity.cs]

Please help me so that I can populate ListView with the data.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tired to clean and rebuild your solution? Or you should check the exception line's every class to make sure that they are using the right .dll file.

Comment: Still not working